# Devilspie window focus

Tags: gnome, window, focus, devilspie

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I'm using devilspie to undecorate the GNOME Terminal windows. It works well except when a terminal window is launched, it is not focused and shortcuts like alt-tab, alt-`, or alt-esc do not work at all (not even ctrl-alt-tab). I have to click on the window with mouse pointer and then the window is focused and everything is back to normal. I know it may seem like just a minor annoyance but its in the way of me feeling all warm and cozy on my desktop :-)

My .ds file for GNOME Terrminal looks like this:

```
(if (is (window_role) "borderless") 
  (begin
    (undecorate)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I went through the manpage again and realized I had to add a (focus) parameter to my .ds file. Now it looks like this:

```
(if (is (window_role) "borderless") 
  (begin
    (undecorate)
    (focus)
  )
)
```

Works like a charm :)